# Different storyboard approach for iPhone and iPad using UIStackView and Auto Layout best practices

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, uistackview

For a very large ios project with the huge amount of features and complex user interface, would like to have the suggestions for following -

1. Will it be more easy and convenient if we use different storyboards
   for iPhone and iPad Screen sizes as developers used to do a couple of years back when UIStackView was not there?
2. What are the best practices to achieve the complex UI using storyboards, Auto Layout and also have a maintainable code? Please share your experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Will it be more easy and convenient if we use different storyboards for iPhone and iPad Screen sizes as developers used to do a couple of years back when UIStackView was not there?

Using different types of storyboard / xib will increases your bundle size. So it is not a good idea. Before xcode-7, developers do not have any good choice instead of this. Now you can use auto-layout, it can easily maintain your whole screen.

If your design is something like master-detail (like device setting) then you can use different VC's.

> 2. What are the best practices to achieve the complex UI using storyboards, Auto Layout and also have a maintainable code? Please share your experiences.

You can auto-layout, size classes, even vary of traits is more helpful to maintain the designs.

Comment: Ok. Nice suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to use Adaptive Layout with Size Classes and Auto Layout.

On quite a large universal projet, it saved me a lot of time, especially, as you pointed out, since `UIStackView`!

https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started

Using sub storyboards is also a great relief on very large projects.

Having two sets of storyboards is quite painful as you have to duplicate many things. I only use a specific storyboard, when the UI on both platforms is **really really** different.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I added a few things to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use only storyboard for iPhone and iPad , where you can create constraints in proportional to screen size  , and tweak   constants with add variations plus using size classes for handling screen variations with adaptive layout